# Does "broadcast-address" needs to be within defined subnet in dhcpd.conf?

Tags: networking, dhcp, vlan, local-area-network, dhcp-server

Ideally, broadcast address should be last address of defined subnet.But I don't see dhcp server enforces such restriction.A brodcast-address defined outside subnet in dhcpd.conf is accepted by dhcp server?

e.g. below configuration for broadcast-address is valid, BUT how:
subnet 10.10.10.0 subnet 255.255.255.0 {
    option broadcast-address 20.20.20.20;
}

why dhcp server accepts broadcast address 20.20.20.20 for subnet 10.10.10.0/24?

Comment: A broadcast address, by definition, is the all-ones address of the network; in effect, the last address of the network. That is built into IPv4 (IPv6 doesn't have broadcast). See _[RFC 919, BROADCASTING INTERNET DATAGRAMS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc919)_ and _[RFC 922, BROADCASTING INTERNET DATAGRAMS IN THE PRESENCE OF SUBNETS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc922)_.

Comment: I guess the DHCP server simply validate its option statements. I think they haven't bothered doing it, since the `option` things are sent to the clients, and don't affect the operation of the DHCP server itself.